# Ignore Zeros Not Working When Trying To Open Tar

Tags: tar, gzip

I have a backup file from my system admins called backup.tar.gz. They mentioned that I need to use the --ignore-zeros/-i command when unzipping the file. However when I run the command as suggested

```
tar -zxvfi backup.tar.gz
```

I get

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'i'
```

How can I correct this?

**Note**
When I try:

```
tar -zxvif backup.tar.gz
```

I get the following:

```
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
```

**Update**
The output of

```
tar --version
```

is

```
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

I am using a Mac with OS X El Capitan v10.11

Comment: What kind of system (OS, distro/version) is this on?  Could you edit the output of `tar --version` into your question?  I fear this may be a system without GNU tar, like an old Solaris box, or perhaps AIX (shudder).

Comment: I updated my question with the info

Answer (score 4):

The `-f` option needs to be last one, as the following argument specifies the archive to process.

```
tar -zxvif backup.tar.gz
```

---

Note: My answer was correct for the GNU version of `tar` as used on most Linux systems. 
As you are using `BSD tar` on MacOS, the `-i` option is not available, it's exclusive to `GNU tar`. You could get it by installing e.g. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or maybe MacPorts.

Comment: When I run it that way I get the following: tar -zxvif backup.tar.gz
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help

Comment: See my edit for more info

Comment: It is worth mentioning that while `-i` is not present in BSD tar, the full option `--ignore-zeros` works just fine.